# Reading JSON from a link

Tags: go

I want to return the string returned from this [link](https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=k66yDaGk4Dybnv6N-K_vmKJkfQxaclLqDyAlEn3TaOZumYS5iiMvS-lMDwhnsulkDB1y5FM4l-L91JAeOcuuSrcHw7Wg-59Wm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnGb6k9xaGtOX6M1tIiG811CRpk9nXl8ZKS7UJTno1dvQXMe1kqfAj8WxsSkLor-EqzOmbnRGq-tk&lib=M0B6GXYh0EOYMkP7qr1Xy9xw8GuJxFqGH), and build a JSON object based on the returned data, I wrote the below code that is reading the url and getting the string correctly, but it fails in building the JSON object, and do not return anything!

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Product struct {
    ProductId   string `json:"id"`
    ProductName string `json:"description"`
}

func main() {
    url := "https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=WBSJPDNSN6X1FCYeXsR6TDaDval0vdvmSoMmXFhGbt5sfK0ia80Dp7kPD27GLpZbYz8vrwfDiUecI2oGMjEtgfL5o8Da25T1m5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnGb6k9xaGtOX6M1tIiG811CRpk9nXl8ZKS7UJTno1dvQXMe1kqfAj8WxsSkLor-EqzOmbnRGq-tk&lib=M0B6GXYh0EOYMkP7qr1Xy9xw8GuJxFqGH"
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    htmlData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body) //<--- here!

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // print out
    fmt.Println(string(htmlData))

    var product Product
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(htmlData)), &product)

    fmt.Printf("ID: %s, Description: %s", product.ProductId, product.ProductName)
}
```

Output:

```sh
{"user":[{"ProductId":1,"ProductName":"Helmet"},{"ProductId":2,"ProductName":"Glove"},{"ProductId":3,"ProductName":"Detecttor"}]}
ID: , Description:
```

Comment: That struct does not match the JSON data. It has a "user" field containing an array of `Product`s

Comment: @Burak Serdar, so how to treat it correctly, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- The unmarshal target struct must match the data,

```golang
type Data struct {
   User []Product `json:"user"`
}
```

2- The fields types should be matching, so `ProductID` should be `uint`

3- The json OP got in output should match the tags used, `json:"id"` should be replaced by `json:"ProductId"` same for `description`

```golang
type Product struct {
    ProductId   uint `json:"ProductId"`
    ProductName string `json:"ProductName"`
}
```

So, a working code is:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Data struct {
    User []Product `json:"user"`
}
type Product struct {
    ProductId   uint   `json:"ProductId"`
    ProductName string `json:"ProductName"`
}

func main() {
    url := "https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=WBSJPDNSN6X1FCYeXsR6TDaDval0vdvmSoMmXFhGbt5sfK0ia80Dp7kPD27GLpZbYz8vrwfDiUecI2oGMjEtgfL5o8Da25T1m5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnGb6k9xaGtOX6M1tIiG811CRpk9nXl8ZKS7UJTno1dvQXMe1kqfAj8WxsSkLor-EqzOmbnRGq-tk&lib=M0B6GXYh0EOYMkP7qr1Xy9xw8GuJxFqGH"
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    htmlData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body) 

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // print out
    fmt.Println(string(htmlData))

    //var product Product
    var data Data
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(htmlData)), &data)

    fmt.Println(data)
    fmt.Println(data.User)
    fmt.Println(data.User[0])
    fmt.Printf("id: %v, description: %s", data.User[0].ProductId, data.User[0].ProductName)
}
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that the json OP got in output does not match the tags they've used (although the fields do match). So if that's the actual json and those are the actual tags, then not even the correct Go structure will help them.

Comment: Once I tried `fmt.Printf("id: %s, description: %s", data.User[0].ProductId, data.User[0].ProductName)` I got the `ProductName` only, and the `ProductId` is empty!, I fixed it, the type should be a number.